# How to write file chunk by chunk in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, file-transfer

I am trying to write buffer data into a file. I receive buffer data in a callback function continuously. I need to read the buffer and save it in a file as it is received. This will be repeated till i get complete file,i get data chunk of 4k in size. But below code either throws an exception or output file is corrupted. Please let me know how to do this in winRT.

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(strFileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
public async void Receive(byte[] buffer)
{
  using (var ostream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
  {
     await ostream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the signature of `Receive`. Because it's `void`, it is not awaited and you can run to writting processes in the same time (that's probably what causes the exception, and/or corrupted datas).

I suggest to use this instead :

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(strFileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
public async Task Receive(byte[] buffer)
{
  using (var ostream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
  {
     await ostream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

And call with

```
await Receive(b);
```